# I'd like to remark about the unremarkable [mark] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Anyone wanna tell me what the [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mark) tag is about? I'm looking only for experts in [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mark). Oh wait, there aren't any? In that case, let's untag the ~125 questions with this stain --- I mean mark.

Comment: Err the tag lines for tags are so annoying :|

Comment: Well there are *some* questions where it could be applied...such as those that directly related to the `<mark>` HTML element...wouldn't make much sense to remove it there...or would it?

Comment: @Paulie_D - I didn't check but do we have tags for every HTML element? Even if we did, wouldn't `HTML-mark` be better than just `mark`?

Comment: Oh I'm not sure about what the tag *should* be, I'm open to a new tag but wholesale blind untagging may not be the best option. Just indicating that *some* caution might be advisable.

Comment: It would be quite a re[mark]able club of experts.

Comment: Oh yeah. Real [mark]smanship!

Comment: @JonH Oh, come on. We don't have to hate fun *all* the time :c

Comment: A man mark may be created this ! or mark may be markup language.

Answer (score 15):

This tag now has no questions in it and has effectively burnt down. How? No idea.

Maybe the editors decided to follow [Shog's procedure on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or even the [SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process) to make sure that the tag wasn't simply edited out.
Maybe the time was taken to carefully improve that specific part of Stack Overflow.

Since the question doesn't even answer Shog's point above on ***Does this tag even need to be burninated?***, I highly doubt it.

This request is of very poor quality (see Shog's answer), the fact that it was acted upon so quickly is an indication that something is very wrong with the way burnination requests are handled on the site.

Too bad.

Comment: Regarding the edits, it seems most of them (~100) were made by [Bob Jarvis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/213136/bob-jarvis?tab=activity&sort=revisions) - so queries about how the burnination process was applied here could probably be directed towards him.

Comment: Please note that the SOCVR doesn't have the exclusive rights to burnination...

Answer (score -18):

Most browsers will display the  element with the following default values:

```
mark {
background-color: yellow;
color: black;
}
```

So it does have a use - it's used for coders too lazy to define styles for any other element, even the lowly `span` tag

Comment: The question isn't about whether the `mark` HTML element is useful or not, but whether we should have a tag [tag:mark] or not.

Comment: Doesn't the tag refer to the HTML element?

Comment: That is the question ;). We don't know what the tag is, if its useful or properly used.

Comment: Gaahh! But my answer answered the question that was questioned. The tag is about the HTML tag, and people are posting questions about the HTML element, whose use was used to make up my answer

Comment: Problem is, they are not. Look at this question tagged [tag:mark] for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/32468793/1743880. It has nothing to do the with HTML mark element...

Comment: ... and anyway, html-`<mark>` doesn't really warrant a tag. Actually, adding a tag for each class/function/tag/object/... is a bad idea, unless it denotes a full area of expertise.